# Edittext android:textColor not working on first input

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` field in my layout which I want to style the `textColor` to my `@color/fire_red color`. To do this I set the `android:textColor` in the XML to that value.

Now whenever I start typing, the typed value is black and will only change to red after I dropped focus on that field.

Is it possible to fix this? I'm testing on HTC one X Android 4.3.

**EDIT**

The XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/InputLayout"
    android:id="@+id/account_view">
    <TextView
        style="@style/InputLabel"
        android:text="@string/account" />
    <EditText
        style="@style/InputField" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Style:

```
<style name="InputField">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/field_height</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">25</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/fire_red</item>
    <item name="android:hint"></item>
</style>
```

Comment: the answer is updated please have a look

Comment: I did, and still not the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:textColor="@color/red">

    </EditText>
```

**color.xml** (res/values/color.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#900</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<style name="InputField" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">`

instead of

```
<style name="InputField">
```

or do something like this If you wants to do progrmatically and if you want to change programming approach

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
               //CHANGE COLORS ACCORDINGLY

                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                ((EditText) v).setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
               //CHANGE COLORS ACCORDINGLY
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                ((EditText) v).setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }
    });
```

else you can do as follows

in `color.xml (res/values/color.xml)` have a resource as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="text_color">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

and access it as `android:textColor="@color/text_color"` at yours `EditText` in yours layout.